# Test convergence of alternating series for real alpha smaller or equal to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Test convergence of following series for $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$:
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n*\ln^{\alpha}(n)}$

I proved that series converge absolutely for $\alpha>1$ but I can't find anything for all other alphas. I am looking for the solution for $\alpha\in[-\infty,1]$

Answer (score 1):

The alternating series test tells us this is convergent for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that for negative $\alpha$, the sequence $a_n=\frac{e^{1/n}}{n\ln^{\alpha}n}$ might not be decreasing from the first value ($n=2$) but it will be decreasing for sufficiently large values of $n$, i.e. for $n\geq N$ where $N$ is some constant.

As for absolute convergence,
$$\frac{1}{n\ln^{\alpha}n}<\frac{e^{1/n}}{n\ln^{\alpha}n}<\frac{3}{n\ln^{\alpha}n} $$
and since $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^{\alpha}n}$ converges iff $\alpha>1$, the given series is absolutely convergent only for $\alpha>1$.